# How to continue computation while pyaudio is playing a .wav file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, pyaudio

I am using pyaudio to play a .wav file.

I also have cv2 displaying the webcam on the screen.

When I call the function that plays the audio file, everything stops until it is finished playing. That includes the webcam feed and all other computation.

Is there a way for me to play the .wav file with my function while not effecting everything else. I would think that multiprocessing would be something to use, but after a few hours of attempting this, I am not really getting anywhere.

All help is appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't really need another process, another thread will do just fine. Have a look at the [Python Threading Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)

Comment: Thank you! I looked into this and it was totally what I needed :)